# Should I use the same CSR to create the Development and Push Certificate?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, apple-push-notifications, app-store-connect

I have a quick question.

Should I use the same CSR file to create the development certificate and the push certificate? What's the recommended way to create these certificates?

Xcode 6 is already managing my development and production certificate. Do I have to create the push certificate manually or is Xcode 6 able to take care of it?

Thank you.

Kind regards, Philipp

Comment: Yes you can use same CSR for development certificate and the push certificate. but for push certificate you have create it manually.

Comment: Thank you! Xcode 6 automatically created my development and production certificate. Unfortunately, I don't have the corresponding CSR file. Should I create a new CSR file for the push certificate or is it possible to retrieve the CSR file used by Xcode 6?

Comment: You have to create the new CSR file manually for push certificate